# Unable to print form submission result

Tags: 7, forms, blocks

The structure of my form is as follows:

Form is built here

> function mymodule_member_search_form

The form submission processing happens in the callback function

> _mymodule_search_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state)

Here I am able to get the results and do the various processing I want and the final result I have stored in

```
if(isset($myvalues)){
        $form['results'] = array(
            '#type'     => 'item',
            '#markup'   => $myvalues,
        );
    }
```

But the values are not printed on the page after form submission, I have also set

```
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
```

in the above submission function

What am I missing here?

Additional Information is this form I have added as a block. So do I have to pass this ass the result of block? If yes, how do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: May you share the code you are using? Without seeing the actual code it is rather difficult to answer the question without guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you start with a fresh form in `mymodule_member_search_form()`, i.e. with `$form = array();`. Is it correct? If so, your `$form['results']` are not in the form returned by `mymodule_member_search_form()`. You should either do the processing in form callback itself or fetch results from the form prior to redefining it.

Comment: Yes it has the $form = array(); which redefines the form. Although the submission callback function does have the value. It seems likes its lost because of this fresh form. Currently I just store the results in a session and display from there. Not sure whats the alternative for that?

Comment: You can e.g. pull results from `$form_state` in `mymodule_member_search_form()`.

Comment: Thanks for working with me on this. Clearing this further, I am able to pull and manipulate results, I am having trouble with displaying it on the page after the form reloads. Any clues for that? Thanks.

Comment: @pal4life, it seems to me we have figured out how you can do it. To sum up: you should set `$form['results']` in `mymodule_member_search_form()`.